# JSON push to nested JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nested-loops

I am new to JSON and I am preparing an JSON object on client side from the response received from server.
I want the data looks like below

```
[
 {"number" : "456" , 
  "effort" : [{
    "effort_type" : "A", 
     "act_effort" : 10 },
    {"effort_type" : "B", 
     "act_effort" : 20 }]
 },
 {"number" : "123" , 
  "effort" : [{
    "effort_type" : "A", 
     "act_effort" : 5},
    {"effort_type" : "B", 
     "act_effort" : 30},
     {"effort_type" : "C", 
     "act_effort" : 15}]
 }
]
```

I am creating this JSON from the response received from server as below

```
$http.get('/colist').success(function(response) {   
    //console.log ("i GET the data of projects");

            $scope.project = response;
 }
```

Below is the code to prepare my second json object

```
 var actEffortData = [];
 var dataSource = $scope.project;
 for(i=0; i<dataSource.length; i++){
    var dupCoFound="N";
    var currentNumber=dataSource[i].number;
    var currentEffort = parseInt(dataSource[i].act_effort); 
    var currentEffortType= dataSource[i].effort_type;
    if(i==0){
       actEffortData.push({ 
           number : currentNumber,
           effort : {
               effort_type:currentEffortType,
               act_effort:currentEffort
           }
       }); 
    } else {
        for(k=0; k < actEffortData.length; k++){
           var dupCEffFound="N";
           if(actEffortData[k].number == currentNumber){
              for(n=0; n < actEffortData[0].effort.length; n++){
                  if(actEffortData[k].effort[n].effort_type == currentEffortType){
                      var currentEffortTemp = actEffortData[k].effort[n].act_effort + currentEffort;
                      actEffortData[k].effort[n].act_effort = currentEffortTemp;
                      dupCEffFound="Y";
                      break;
                  }
              }
              if(dupCEffFound == "N"){
                  var tempActEffort =[];
                  tempActEffort = actEffortData[k].effort;
                  tempActEffort.push({
                      effort_type:currentEffortType,
                      act_effort:currentEffort
                  });  
              }
              dupCoFound = "Y";
              break;
          }
      }
      if (dupCoFound=="N"){
          actEffortData.push({ 
              number : currentNumber,
              effort : {
                  effort_type:currentEffortType,
                  act_effort:currentEffort
              }
          }); 
      }
 }
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
 Error: tempActEffort.push is not a function
```

Can anyone show me how to achieve this one? 
Please note that actual code has functionality more than the above one, so you might find redundant variables usage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see line 'tempActEffort = actEffortData[k].effort;' no longer allows your variable 'tempActEffort' to act as array…!

Comment: what if in your server side you already prepare the json data to your client side when the response is receive by the client server.. just a suggestion

Comment: @Oli Soproni B. I need multiple JSON objects, each have different structure based on few things to be mapped. I can't prepare jason data on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed one thing in your code at:

```
var tempActEffort =[];
tempActEffort = actEffortData[k].effort;
```

Here, you declared a variable 'tempActEffort' as an array.Then you are directly initializing some value as 'tempActEffort = actEffortData[k].effort' to it so that its type got changed from array to resulting type. So, then push is not a function defined on it as it is not an array type at the moment.

So, instead of assigning value as 'tempActEffort = actEffortData[k].effort' change it as:

```
tempActEffort.push(actEffortData[k].effort);
```

Comment: I changed as you suggested. The error is gone, but it is not working still. I have added few     console.log() statements to check. effort values are coming as undefined. Can you please help me with it ? Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DivB/gwkrg81a/4/ Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if

```
tempActEffort = actEffortData[k].effort;
```

returned an array object. Push can be applied only to array